# What libraries should I use for E-Commerce

Tags: transactions, wallet, client, development

We are developing some automated payment functions for Bitcoin. We want to automate transactions via a backend server setup; what libraries would be best suited?

I've found two libraries so far:

- Java has BitcoinJ
- C++ has bitcoin-qt

Would a thin or selfish client suffice ?

Do they support QR codes ?

P.S. I would prefer a Java over C++ coming from a C# background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitcoinJ is fully featured and recently updated.

There is also BitcoinSharp if you are from a c# background. This is a direct port of BitcoinJ (it   may be slightly out of date as a new BitcoinJ has been released recently).

As far as im aware it does not support native QR codes but https://btc.to/ has a http request which can generate QR codes (https://btc.to/1PeizMg76Cf96nUQrYg8xuoZWLQozU5zGW/qr) if you dont want to use your own.

A thin or selfish client may be suitable it really depends on what your application is, your confidence in the network and risk involved with your application in general.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a solution using bitcoind (bitcoin-qt).

It was very easy with PHP + RPC Class, but bitcoind has some limitations which make it not very suited as a backend/library.

Comment: I was looking for java or C# as PHP ..thanks